# Not raise exception on serializer with partial = true

Tags: django-rest-framework

As you see on the code. The exception does not raise when i add partial=True, It work ok with partial=False

Rest django framework

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
class AField(serializers.Serializer):
    afield = serializers.CharField()
    xfed = serializers.CharField()

class BField(serializers.Serializer):
    bfield = AField(many=True, required=False)


data = {
    "bfield":[{},{}]
}

BField(data=data, partial=True).is_valid(raise_exception=True)
```

Comment: What's your problem? The code you show behaves as intended. With `partial=True`, you allow some fields to be omitted, so no exception. With `partial=False`, you get an exception because some fields are missing (`afield` and `xfed`).

Comment: But i just want partial = True apply to BField not AField.

Comment: Well I don't really understand why you want to do that but I don't think that's possible (natively, I mean, maybe you can achieve that by writing a custom validator).